# mysql error 1215 cannot add foreign key contraint

Tags: mysql

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS desk;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS user;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS authority;

CREATE TABLE authority
(
    authorityId     INT             NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    deskId          INT             DEFAULT 0,              
    authorityName   VARCHAR(50)     NOT NULL,
    descriptions    VARCHAR(100)    NOT NULL,
    userLevel       TINYINT         NOT NULL,
    actions         VARCHAR(300)    DEFAULT NULL,
    setDate         TIMESTAMP       DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);

CREATE TABLE desk
(
    deskId          INT             NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    deskName        CHAR(50)        NOT NULL,
    deskLink        VARCHAR(100)    NOT NULL,
    details         VARCHAR(350)    DEFAULT NULL,
    setDate         TIMESTAMP       NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    closeDate       TIMESTAMP       DEFAULT NULL,
    userId          INT             DEFAULT NULL,                   
    status          TINYINT(1)          DEFAULT 0
);

CREATE TABLE user 
(
    userId      INT                 NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    userName    CHAR(150)           NOT NULL,
    password    VARCHAR(500)        NOT NULL,
    department  VARCHAR(150)        DEFAULT NULL,
    deskId      INT                 NOT NULL,
    status      TINYINT(1)          DEFAULT NULL,
    userLevel   TINYINT             NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (deskId) REFERENCES desk (deskId) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (userLevel) REFERENCES authority (userLevel)
);
```

**Error while executing query.** 
Error Code: 1215 .Cannot add foreign key contraint

I have tried many way but still cannot solve the problem, i tried change userLevel type to INT both table user and authority but nothing went to better

I really not know how to fix this problem, please help

Comment: Your second query for creating desk table fails , and so the third query.
As  third table user  has reference to desk table(which was not created) , so you are getting error "Cannot add foreign key contraint". please check your second query

Comment: i tried to delete all 3 comment on top " DROP TABLE IF EXIST " but nothing better , still that error "Erorr 1215"

Comment: added steps to resolve your problem, please refer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run Following queries

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS desk;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS user;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS authority;


CREATE TABLE authority
(
    authorityId     INT             NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    deskId          INT             DEFAULT 0,              
    authorityName   VARCHAR(50)     NOT NULL,
    descriptions    VARCHAR(100)    NOT NULL,
    userLevel       TINYINT         NOT NULL,
    actions         VARCHAR(300)    DEFAULT NULL,
    setDate         TIMESTAMP       DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,    
    index `cr_index` (userLevel)
);

CREATE TABLE desk
(
    deskId          INT             NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    deskName        CHAR(50)        NOT NULL,
    deskLink        VARCHAR(100)    NOT NULL,
    details         VARCHAR(350)    DEFAULT NULL,
    setDate         TIMESTAMP       NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    closeDate       TIMESTAMP       DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
    userId          INT             DEFAULT NULL,                   
    status          TINYINT(1)          DEFAULT 0
);


CREATE TABLE `user` 
(
    userId      INT                 NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    userName    CHAR(150)           NOT NULL,
    password    VARCHAR(500)        NOT NULL,
    department  VARCHAR(150)        DEFAULT NULL,
    deskId      INT                 NOT NULL,
    status      TINYINT(1)          DEFAULT NULL,
    userLevel   TINYINT           NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (deskId) REFERENCES desk (deskId) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (userLevel) REFERENCES authority (userLevel)
);
```

In your query you write timestamp default value `NULL` and you can create a non index key `userLevel` as a foreign key so from your query remove default value or change the default value `0000-00-00 00:00:00`(in desk table) and add index in `userLevel` column (in authority table)
I hope this will work for you

Comment: Thanks a lot, you save my life :)

Answer (score 1):

Follow below steps

1) You must change your second query to

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS desk;

CREATE TABLE desk
(
    deskId          INT             NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    deskName        CHAR(50)        NOT NULL,
    deskLink        VARCHAR(100)    NOT NULL,
    details         VARCHAR(350)    DEFAULT NULL,
    setDate         TIMESTAMP       NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    closeDate       TIMESTAMP       NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    userId          INT             DEFAULT NULL,                   
    status          TINYINT(1)          DEFAULT 0
);
```

2) As your column **authority.userLevel** is not a primary key and you want to use it as foreign key in other table you need to create index on  authority.userLevel column

**use below query**

```
ALTER TABLE `authority` ADD INDEX `UserLevelIndex` (`userLevel`);
```

3) Run your third query as it is to create user table